# Design time rendering of UserControls in custom Region/RegionManager

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I really liked the navigation implementation done by the MS Prism framework, but I don't need all of the features and I've been having issues with transient lifetime management of views and view models. So, I poked through the code and reimplemented my own Region/Region Manager, adding some additional functionallity.

Everything works great so far, but there is some design time support I'd like but don't have a clue in how to implement. I've added a DefaultViewType attached property. I'd love to be able to render that view in the designer.

Another weirdness is that Visual Studio (or Resharper) reports the following issue in the designer, which is untrue as far as I can tell:

'RegionName' property was already registered by 'ContentControl'.

Here's the code (also available at https://github.com/agartee/StackOverFlowRegionManagerQuestion.git):

My RegionManager is a service that subscribes to MVVM Light messages of type, NavigationRequestMessage:

```
public class RegionManager : IRegionManager
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, ContentControl> _regions =
        new Dictionary<string, ContentControl>();

    public RegionManager(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        messenger.Register<NavigationRequestMessage>(this, Navigate);
    }

    public void RegisterRegion(string regionName, ContentControl region)
    {
        if (_regions.ContainsKey(regionName))
            _regions.Remove(regionName);

        _regions.Add(regionName, region);
    }

    public void Navigate(NavigationRequestMessage message)
    {
        if (!_regions.ContainsKey(message.RegionName)) return;

        var targetRegion = _regions[message.RegionName];

        if (message.ViewType != null)
        {
            var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UserControl>(message.ViewType.Name);
            targetRegion.Content = view;
        }
        else
        {
            targetRegion.Content = null;
        }
    }
}

public class NavigationRequestMessage
{
    public string RegionName { get; private set; }
    public Type ViewType { get; private set; }

    public NavigationRequestMessage(string regionName, Type viewType)
    {
        RegionName = regionName;
        ViewType = viewType;
    }
}
```

Region houses the attached properties:

```
public static class Region
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegionNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RegionName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ContentControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, RegionNameChanged));

    public static string GetRegionName(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(RegionNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRegionName(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(RegionNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultViewTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DefaultViewType",
        typeof(Type),
        typeof(ContentControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static Type GetDefaultViewType(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Type)element.GetValue(DefaultViewTypeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDefaultViewType(UIElement element, Type value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DefaultViewTypeProperty, value);
    }

    private static void RegionNameChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var regionName = (string)e.NewValue;
        var region = (ContentControl)dependencyObject;

        RoutedEventHandler regionOnLoaded = null;
        regionOnLoaded = (sender, args) =>
        {
            region.Loaded -= regionOnLoaded;

            RegisterRegion(regionName, region);
            NavigateToDefaultView(dependencyObject);

        };
        region.Loaded += regionOnLoaded;
    }

    private static void RegisterRegion(string regionName, ContentControl region)
    {
        var navigationService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        navigationService.RegisterRegion(regionName, region);
    }

    public static ContentControl GetParentView(DependencyObject child)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        var parentWindow = parent as Window;
        if (parentWindow != null)
            return parentWindow;

        var parentUserControl = parent as UserControl;
        return parentUserControl ?? GetParentView(parent);
    }

    private static void NavigateToDefaultView(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        var regionName = (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(RegionNameProperty);
        var defaultViewType = (Type)dependencyObject.GetValue(DefaultViewTypeProperty);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(regionName) || defaultViewType == null)
            return;

        var navigationService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        navigationService.Navigate(new NavigationRequestMessage(regionName, defaultViewType));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted to accomplish with the below changes:

```
public class Region : Behavior<ContentControl>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultViewTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DefaultViewType", 
        typeof(Type),
        typeof(Region), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(UserControl)));

    public Type DefaultViewType
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(DefaultViewTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DefaultViewTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegionNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RegionName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Region),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string RegionName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RegionNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RegionNameProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        ShowDefaultView();
        RegisterRegionWithManager();
    }

    private void ShowDefaultView()
    {
        if (DefaultViewType == null)
            return;

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(AssociatedObject))
        {
            var constructorInfo = DefaultViewType.GetConstructors().First();
            var parameters = new List<object>();
            constructorInfo.GetParameters().ToList().ForEach(p => parameters.Add(null));

            AssociatedObject.Content = constructorInfo.Invoke(parameters.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Current;
            AssociatedObject.Content = serviceLocator.GetInstance(DefaultViewType);    
        }
    }

    private void RegisterRegionWithManager()
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(AssociatedObject))
            return;

        var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Current;
        var navigationService = serviceLocator.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

        if (navigationService != null)
            navigationService.RegisterRegion(RegionName, AssociatedObject);
    }
}
```